# Is it possible to send an extra argument or data when interacting with a contract?

Tags: transactions

Take the `transfer` function of the DAI contract as example.
It allows only two arguments: `dst` and `wad`.

This is how the decoded data input looks like on a [sample transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe9da4e0f9fd42bcfa087c8e6d1ba635be0a59bd1679d3996171e1a261f61462b):

```
Function: transfer(address dst, uint256 wad)

MethodID: 0xa9059cbb
[0]:  0000000000000000000000006262998ced04146fa42253a5c0af90ca02dfd2a3
[1]:  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002c3c465ca58ec0000
```

Is it possible to attach some extra data when calling the `transfer` function, so that the decoded data input looks as follows:

```
Function: transfer(address dst, uint256 wad)

MethodID: 0xa9059cbb
[0]:  0000000000000000000000006262998ced04146fa42253a5c0af90ca02dfd2a3
[1]:  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002c3c465ca58ec0000
[2]:  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000fede
```

(obviously without the transaction being reverted or something)

If not possible, is there any other way to attach a message to a transaction that interacts with a contract?

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to achieve by passing another argument? I mean, even if that was possible (and maybe it is somehow, for all I know), it's not like the function contains any code which handles that extra argument.

Comment: The idea is to send a message with the transaction

Comment: Yeah, I understand the idea, I just don't understand the point in it (sending a message to someone who isn't going to do anything about it).

Comment: Not that someone but a third party listening to that kind of transactions

Comment: @viarnes If the idea is to sort of hide the communication, you'd be better off using only the available parameters and have a different detection method.

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd imagine that the transaction would fail as no function with such signature is found.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen: I'd imagine that the signature (`MethodID: 0xa9059cbb` in this example) would be found alright, because it is already in the deployed bytecode, and this user keeps it as is. But I'd also imagine that the transaction would revert with an Invalid-Jump opcode or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

It is up to each contract what they will do with extra data in a transaction's input field.

- It can ignore any extra data
- It can revert if they receive more thant than they were expecting.

Unfortunatelly there is no standard way to add extra metadata to a transaction to a contract.

If target is an EOA you can add any information you want to input field.

---

Example to append data to a ERC20 transfer event

```
const message = '686f6c61'
const data = token.methods.transfer(recipient, amount).encodeABI()

const tx = {
  nonce: '0x00',
  gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
  gasLimit: '0xea60',
  to: token.options.address,
  value: '0x00',
  data: data + message
};

const signedTx = new Tx(tx, {'chain':'ropsten'});
signedTx.sign(privateKey);

const serializedTx = signedTx.serialize();
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
.on('receipt', console.log);
```

Comment: How can a function access arbitrary parameter data? Probably only the fallback function can do that - otherwise the signature wouldn't match?

Comment: @LauriPeltonen It is possible to access raw input data with `msg.data`, or from assembly with `calldataload()`.

Comment: Is there any non-standard way?Also, can you give an example of a contract ignoring the extra data without reverting?

Comment: @viarnes A non-standard is to append to input data, but you have no guarantee that it will work. Most contracts ignore additional data, but a few year ago it was popular to add explicit checks like `require(msg.data.length <= xxx)`.

Comment: I understand the risks. Would you add to your anwser the non-standard way to interact with a smart contract sending additional data? I would love an `ethers` or `web3js` example but everything will work.

Comment: @viarnes I've appended a possible example

Comment: +1 to this answer. For the curious, this reminds of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33590/dealing-with-the-short-address-attack and another answer by Ismael.  Should there be a question what security vulnerabilities there can be by sending additional data? I can't think of any but hackers are more creative.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael! I tried to test your code on localhost (using Buidler) but I get the following: `Error: Returned error: Incompatible EIP155-based V 38 and chain id 31337. See the second parameter of the Transaction constructor to set the chain id.`. I took a look into EIP155 and realized that is not possible to create a `Tx` in a `localhost` chain. I'll try later on `ropsten` but if you find an alternative rather than using `new Tx(tx, {'chain':'ropsten'});` it would be awesome. Thanks again!

Comment: @viarnes It is a bit more complicated for custom blockchain but you can read the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm/tree/master/packages/tx#chain-and-hardfork-support)